# How to clear background noises with sox

Tags: audio, sox, audacity

Is it possible to convert a mp4 file to mp3 or flac, clearing background noises in the process?

Or is it possible to run audacity totally trough shell, No GUI?

Comment: Why kind of noise are we talking of? White noise or random people chatting in the background or bangs, scratch or cough noises in a classical music concert recording... How would you identify that noise with audacity?

Comment: Class room noises. A bit of chit chat, a bit of paper noises. And the truth is I don't know yet. It is a bit new to me.

Comment: Is it a stereo recording? Please add the extra information to you question by clicking the [edit] link

Comment: Some of the file will be stereo others not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the background noise has some repetitive structure to it, you can remove it with the noiseprof and noisered effects of sox, see e.g. [this script](https://gist.github.com/devoncrouse/5534261). Relevant bits repeated for convenience:

```bash
# Create background noise profile from mp3
/usr/bin/sox noise.mp3 -n noiseprof noise.prof

# Remove noise from mp3 using profile
/usr/bin/sox input.mp3 output.mp3 noisered noise.prof 0.21
```

Audacity currently has [experimental scripting support](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html).